# ML development on data biased by historical treatments

Tags: statistics, machine-learning-model, bias, test

I have a dataset where in each data point was subject to certain treatment (4 different treatments) in the past based on their riskiness. The riskiness was estimated by a logistic regression model in the past. The mapping between riskiness and choice of treatment was decided by a separate policy team.

This model has been used for some time now to make the treatment decisions. Up until now. Now it has been decided to re develop the model based on the recent data.

Now the point is that since previous model was used to decide treatments uptil now, the riskiness lables (target variable) that we have for the recent data are biased by the treatments which were decided by a previous model. This bias incorporates the policy team's bias that used the riskiness score down the line to assign treatments.

My understanding is that, if we do not correct for this bias, we will not be able to correct for the previous model's weak points and also not accomodate the shift in the data landscape.

How do I go about mitigating this bias. I do not have a gold standard as to which treatment is ideal for which kinds of data points.

Comment: I don't really understand this problem. The first model that was trained using logistic regression...how were the labels generated in that case? You don't need any model to learn the relationship between treatments and riskiness because this has already been defined by a human. Therefore, you can just hardcode those rules in code...